# Serve static files from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a .net 6 app that reads files from different zip files on startup and converts them to a list of `Resources`:

```
public class Resource
{
    public string? Id { get; set; }
    public string? MimeType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; } = Array.Empty<byte>();
}
```

Currently, I just keep them in a dictionary in memory and serve them from a controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult GetResource(string id)
{
    var resource = _resourceRepository.Get(id);

    return File(resource.Data, resource.MimeType!);
}
```

I would like to incorporate the static file management in the net framework, but preferably retain the controller so that the clients can get resources using a GET `resource/id`.

I tried to use `app.UseStaticFiles`, set the `RequestPath` to "resource" and store the files without extension and set `ServeUnknownFileTypes = true` which works, I would prefer to keep the extensions to be able to browse the folders manually and keep the content-type header.

Is there any way to manage this through the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already knew that configuring static files middleware is necessary,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0

But you probably didn't notice that you can write your own file provider (instead of the default `PhysicalFileProvider`),

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Microsoft ships an example of `ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider` but it might not work the way you like, so you'd better create your own.